# how to align qtableview row at the right side in pyqt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtableview

How to align the content of the qtable view in the right? I use this class in making my table.

```
class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, datain, headerdata, parent=None, *args): 
        """ datain: a list of lists
            headerdata: a list of strings
        """
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args) 
        self.arraydata = datain
        self.headerdata = headerdata


    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata) 

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        try:
            return len(self.arraydata[0]) 
        except:
            return 0
    def data(self, index, role): 
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant() 
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant() 
        return QVariant(self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()]) 

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):

        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return QVariant(self.headerdata[col])
        return QVariant()

    def sort(self, Ncol, order):
        """Sort table by given column number.
        """
        self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutAboutToBeChanged()"))
        self.arraydata = sorted(self.arraydata, key=operator.itemgetter(Ncol))        
        if order == Qt.DescendingOrder:
            self.arraydata.reverse()
        self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutChanged()"))
```

I would like to align all the currency data type in the right.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look to the [`Qt::ItemDataRole enum`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) (especially the `TextAlignmentRole`).

You can do something like this:

```
def data(self, index, role): 
    if index.isValid():
        return QVariant()

    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        return QVariant(self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()])
    elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
        return QVariant(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

    return QVariant()
```